# Import SQL file in Django (v-2.2)

Tags: django, python-3.x

I have a Django project and I am using  MySQL as default. I already have created and migrated 2 models. Now I have a SQL file. I want to create new models and populate those models with this SQL file. I am using Windows 10.

I have searched this query but did not get working solution.

Comment: What kind of SQL file, can you provide sample of your SQL file?

Comment: It was an old project in php. They gave me a .sql file which contains tables and data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you are looking for [`inspectdb`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/django-admin/#django-admin-inspectdb). Try [Integrating Django with a legacy database](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/howto/legacy-databases/).

- First of all create a database using your SQL file.
- Then add the details of your database into `settings.py` file.
- Just run `python manage.py inspectdb` command, you will see all the table structures in your new database which creates with your SQL file as a Django Models structure. (convert your database into python django model).
- You can get those details as a `.py` by running `python manage.py inspectdb > models_new.py` command.

Now you have all the table structures in that `models.py` file which create in last step.

- Then change your `settings.py` file for old database which you migrated earlier.
- Get those details from `models_new.py` and add into your `app_name/models.py` file and save it.
- Run `python manage.py makemigrations` and `python manage.py migrate`.

I found useful [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ychsJgKoGXQ) tutorial which is not in English, but you can get an idea about your question how to do it.